# Uncaught `TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function` in online server, but not in my local server

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an error `TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function` when logged to my console after i uploaded my files to my online server, but in my local server, this won't appear and my app works fine.

I followed all the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632294/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function) but still doesn't work. And I really don't know how to fix this.

Here's my script below:

```html
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/config/jquery.noty.config.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/grocery_crud/js/common/lazyload-min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/grocery_crud/js/common/list.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/js/flexigrid.js"></script>
```

Please help me. Hope this won't be closed.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you haven't properly included `jquery.dataTables.js`.  Please post the code are you using to include your scripts.

Comment: I already posted my script above.

Comment: Something about your file structure, `base_url()` function, or script src is not correct.  There is no way to tell exactly what's wrong without seeing it on a server, can you post the URL where this is live?

Comment: I already checked the network and a 404 appears in my `jquery.dataTables.min.js`. When i checked it on my server files, it was already uploaded. What's wrong with this? I already tried re-uploading this 4 times.

Comment: my `base_url()` is correct. `jquery` was already uploaded but my `jquery.dataTables.min.js` shows a 404.

Comment: Thats a really strong sign its a pathing issue.  If it shows a 404 when you try and access the file via the browser's address bar, check to make sure the file is in the right folder.  If you can access it in the browser address bar but not programatically, check your code to make sure the pathing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my live server, the pathing of files is case-sensitive. Unlike in my local server, I can just mix cases and no issues found. In my case, when I call the script like this: `<script src="mysite/assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>` , and the path is `assets/js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js` , this won't work on a live server where `datatables` folder is not the same with `dataTables` folder in my path to call that file.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/#introduction), it is telling to include [datatables.min.js](https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js) from the cdn. This script contains a definition of **both** jquery and DataTables.

The second script, [bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js](http://bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js), is trying to patch jquery to add the functions **initDataTables** and **dataTable**.

Therefore, the order matters.

Here is my /symfony/templates/**list.html.twig** file for Symfony 4.2 :

```
<!-- Insert this at the end of your body element, but before the closing tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script> {# Included libraries: jQuery 3 3.2.1, DataTables 1.10.16 #}
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js') }}"></script> {# An omines script that patches jquery : add initDataTables function #}

<script>
$(function() {
    // 'datatable' is defined in the symfony controller.
    // datatable_settings Twig function renders a compact JSON string with the configured settings required for initialization.
    var table = $('#presidents');
    if (table && table.initDataTables)
        table.initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }});
});
</script>
```