# Tried to load angular more than once in Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, symfony

problem

- i was using jquery with angular js .

error

```
angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:12116 TypeError: ha is not a function
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:2:2616), <anonymous>:17:349)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:2:2616), <anonymous>:308:401)
at http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:2:2616
at Function.globalEval (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:2:2627)
at text script (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:4:26788)
at Qc (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:4:18505)
at x (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:4:21926)
at b (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:4:26298)
at Object.send (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:4:26402)
at Function.ajax (http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=1.6.10:4:21703) <div id="wrapper" ui-view="" class="container ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:12116(anonymous function) @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:8976invokeLinkFn @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:8527nodeLinkFn @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:8034compositeLinkFn @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:7435publicLinkFn @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:7309updateView @ angular-ui-router.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:2733(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:2697$broadcast @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:15893$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition @ angular-ui-router.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:2114processQueue @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:14347(anonymous function) @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:14363$eval @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:15574$digest @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:15385$apply @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:15679done @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:10166completeRequest @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:10338requestLoaded @ angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474366451:10279
```

Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/metisMenu.js.map

```
      <div id="wrapper" ui-view="" class="container ng-scope">
```

angular js code

```
 var sbAdmin2 = angular.module('sbAdmin2', ['ui.router','ngSanitize']);


sbAdmin2.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('');

$stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('Dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard/data',
        templateUrl: 'http://localhost/weblogs-s2/web/weblogs_dev.php/dashboard/data'
    })

   })
```

script i have used

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="{{ asset ('common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset ('common/assets/libs/jquery/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('common/assets/libs/angular/source/angular.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}_{{ NOW }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset ('common/assets/libs/angular/source/modules/angular-ui-router.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}_{{ NOW }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset ('common/assets/libs/angular/source/modules/angular-sanitize.js') }}?v={{ app_version }}_{{ NOW }}"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper" ui-view class="container ng-scope" >
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

i have googled

- jquery conflicting with angular js library.
- when i load angular js before jquery application works fine.
- but i need to populate the data in datatable then datatable is is not working.
- which means for datatable  require jquery to first to first load.

what i need

- is it possible to load jquery before angular js library or it may conflicts.

  ```
  problem arise when i was using datatable using jquery then it  would not work when i used jquery after angular js.
  ```

any suggestion is most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Angular v1.3 only supports jQuery v2.1 and above

> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

It looks like you are using jQuery v1.6.10 (if that even exists). Try updating to a newer version of jQuery.

(Also make sure you're using Angular v1.* and not Angular v2.*)

Comment: hi daniel i think we cannot use jquery with angular js

Comment: we are using datatable lib of symfony2 but we are facing angular.js?v=1.6.10_1474973236:12116 TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Comment: You can definitely use jQuery with Angular! Are you including the dataTable script? Make sure you include it after jQuery. Also make sure Angular is included after jQuery

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632294/typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function

Comment: i think im getting error bcs of WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.error

Comment: i have viewd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once